# UITextView bad content offset after animating view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5, uitextview

I have one UITextView which is on the bottom of view. When user tap in it, I need to animate view 150px up. I'm using:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
```

and

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
```

to make this.

On iOS5, it works fine. But on iOS 4.3, when view is animated, content in this UITextView goes few pixels up.

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/1q3e0W2G1M000u1U3w1f

**Someone had similar issues?**

**Code:**

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    if([textView.text isEqualToString:@"Placeholder text"]){
        textView.text = @"";
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.origin.y - 150.0), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    if([textView.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        textView.text = @"Placeholder text";
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.origin.y + 150.0), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need reset content inset of your text view when call method in textViewDidBeginEditing method and after you animation is done...

Try this code:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
   [textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You can also use the constant `UIEdgeInsetsZero`

Answer (score 3):

I found that the accepted answer caused some visual irregularities. The following worked much better for me.

```
textView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
```

Answer (score -4):

Try UITextField to solve this problem.