# UiTextField not animating in properly..instead it's doing an odd masking reveal?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, constraints, animatewithduration

I wasn't quiet sure how to word this, but here goes. 
I have a couple of UIControls that I am sliding into the view with in the viewWillAppear method. The UIControls animate correctly as well as my graphics inside those UIControls, but the UITextField is not. It should be starting to the right 50 points with an alpha of 0 fading into 1. Instead the UITextFields does this odd masking and from the other direction (left to right instead of right to left, as well as a bit higher on the y axis). Does this have something to do with the UITextField not being ready for display when I start my animation? Below is the code.

```
nameOfBillViewConstraint.constant = 50;
nameOfBillView.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:10
                          delay: 0.5
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         nameOfBillViewConstraint.constant = 10;
                         nameOfBillView.alpha = 1.0;
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

Thanks for your help on this.It's more of a visual problem, but I wasn't sure how to display that here...

Comment: Try this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8167907/2700842

Comment: Try adding [self.view layoutIfNeeded] after those first two lines so those constraints are applied before you start your animation.